# ModelForm order field based on count

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm converting a rather complex self-made form into a `ModelForm` in Django. As this form is used in production for over a year, i'm trying to remove as much pitfalls as possible and give the users extra functionality.

I have three models: `Transaction`, `Commission` and `Unit_type`. `Transaction` is the central model in my usage and has a `Unit_type`. The `Commission`is derived from the `Unit_type`'s `base_type`.

```
BASE_CHOICES = (
    ('R', 'rent'),
    ('S', 'sale'),
)

class Unit_type(models.Model):
    unit_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    base_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=BASE_CHOICES)


class Commission(models.Model):
    commission_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    base_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=BASE_CHOICES)


class Transaction(models.Models):
    unit_type = models.ForeignKey(Unit_type)
    commission = models.ForeignKey(Commission, blank=True, null=True)
```

When i display my form i can show only the `Commission`s which have the same base_type as `Unit_type`by using:

```
class TransactionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Transaction

    def __init__(self, unit_type, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TransactionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['commission'].queryset = Commission_type.objects.filter(base_type=unit_type.base_type)
```

I always create my form as `TransactionForm(instance=transaction, unit_type=unit_type)` in my view.

Now, an easy query in MySQL learned me that some `Commission`s are used more or less depending on the `Unit` selected:

```
SELECT `unit_type_id`, `commission_id`, COUNT(*)
FROM `app_transaction`
GROUP BY `unit_type_id`, `commission_id`
```

With as result:

```
+----------------+-----------------+------------+
|  unit_type_id  |  commission_id  |  COUNT(*)  |
+----------------+-----------------+------------+
|             1  |              1  |       367  |
|             1  |              3  |         2  |
|             1  |              4  |        26  |
|             2  |              1  |       810  |
|             2  |              3  |        54  |
|             2  |              4  |       865  |
|             3  |              6  |      2065  |
|             3  |              7  |        16  |
|             3  |              8  |        79  |
+----------------+-----------------+------------+
```

Now i'd like to order my queryset in `self.fields['commission']` based on the above count. I've already tried using `values()` in `__init__()`:

```
def __init__(self, unit, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TransactionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(unit_type=unit)
        transactions = transactions.values('commission').annotate(Count('commission)).order_by('-commission')
```

But now i'm stuck on how i can keep this order in my queryset. Is there an easy way to perform a new queryset based on this `ValuesQuerySet`? Or am i seeing this completely wrong?

Comment: you can try django the aggregation or the annotation methods

Comment: @abda2005 i already use an annotation in my __init__(), now i need a way to put these results in a queryset for my field, something like `self.fields['commission'].queryset = Commission.objects.filter(pk__in=transactions)`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use a kwarg for Count and use the same kwarg in `order_by`

```
transactions = transactions.annotate(commission_count=Count('commission)).order_by('-commission_count')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet

Comment: This gives me back a QuerySet with all the transactions, while in only need to know which `commission`is used the most. I already know that by using the aggregation in my init, i just need to find a way to put it in my field...

Answer (score 1):

Cant you just perform one query operation to set your queryset, as filter() and annotate() aren't terminal clauses?

```
self.fields['commission'].queryset = Commission_type.objects.filter(base_type=unit_type.base_type).annotate(Count('commission)).order_by('-commission')
```

This will answer a queryset based on your filter() and then annotate().